# DIGIX tokens mapped with physcial gold ids?

Tags: go-ethereum, digix

If digix tokens are linked to Physical gold, what will happen to this linkage, if user transfers his tokens to other users.

Comment: The same as if you are transfering house/car/whatever ownership: You don't do it without thinking about it twice. Joke aside, you need person-to-person agreement and transfer proof. However I'm really wondering what could be the benefit of "assetizing" gold.

Comment: That's the point, if person-to-person agreement is required, How exchanges are doing it. For example, If I buy DGX token from a user on an exchange and now I want to redeem it into Physical gold. How DGX will know that my DGX tokens are associated to which Physical gold ids?